# qml parsing QVariant QJsonDocument to js object

Tags: qt, qml

A QVariant I took from C++ contains a QJsonDocument, and I want to convert it to a js object, but I only [found](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html) the use of QJsonDocument in C++. I couldn't find how to use QJsonDocument in qml.

For Example:

**Qml:**

```
function qmlUpdateObject( Object ){
   console.log(Object);
}

// console content: qml: QVariant(QJsonDocument, QJsonDocument({"appDesc":{"description":"SomeDescription","message":"SomeMessage"},"appName":{"description":"Home","imp":["awesome","best","good"],"message":"Welcome"}}))

// I want to get a js object: {"appDesc":{"description":"SomeDescription","message":"SomeMessage"},"appName":{"description":"Home","imp":["awesome","best","good"],"message":"Welcome"}}
```

**C++:**

```
QObject::connect( this, SIGNAL( updateData(QVariant)),
                  viewItem, SLOT( qmlUpdateObject(QVariant)) );

void Controller::setData(QString name)
{
 QFile file("data.json");
 QJsonDocument d = QJsonDocument::fromJson(file.readAll()); 
 QByteArray dataJson = d.toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact);
 emit updateData(dataJson);
}
```

**UPDATE**
Add this line and pass back, qml can successfully parse:

```
QByteArray dataJson = d.toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct QJsonDocument conversion to a js object. One possible solution is to convert the QJsonDocument to QByteArray and export it to QML, and in QML do parse using  `JSON.parse()`:

**C++**

```cpp
QByteArray dataJson = doc.toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact);
// send dataJson to QML
```

**QML**

```
var json = JSON.parse(dataJson)
```

---

**Note:**

- It seems that the OP does not know the good practice of not accessing QML objects from C++ but must create a QObject and export it to QML.
- The example provided by the OP is not necessary to use QJsonDocument since JSON.parse() does the same as `QJsonDocument d = QJsonDocument::fromJson(file.readAll());`.

```cpp
#include <QFile>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

class Controller: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void setData(const QString & filename){
        QFile file(filename);
        if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
            Q_EMIT updateData(file.readAll());
    }
Q_SIGNALS:
    void updateData(const QByteArray & data);
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Controller controller;

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("controller", &controller);
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);
    controller.setData("data.json");

    return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    function qmlUpdateObject( data ){
        var obj = JSON.parse(data)
        console.log(obj);
    }
    Connections{
        target: controller
        onUpdateData: qmlUpdateObject(data)
    }
}
```

Comment: I found that the type return by C ++ is `QVariant`. What type should I change? C++ backend return: `QObject::connect( this, SIGNAL( updateData(QVariant)),`

Comment: @Albert mmm I do not understand you. Provide a [mre] if you want more help.

Comment: I changed my example and tried to make it more complete. I wonder if it helps?

Comment: @Albert Your code is not enough, so please improve it. I need to know what part of your code you call setData and how it gets the viewItem object.

Comment: I successfully parsed it out, use your method, thanks.

Comment: @Albert mmm, I think you are using bad practices so in a moment I will show an example better

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to qt and I'm not familiar with the whole environment and language ..

Comment: @Albert I do not see the use of QJsonDocument necessary

Comment: Thanks, let me take a moment to understand the case you provided

Comment: I tried your case and there was an error in `"Q_EMIT updateData (file.readAll ());"`, error message:  `error: undefined reference to Controller::updateData(QByteArray const&)'`